# Use a static class differently depending on context it was called

Tags: c#

I have a static class whose sole job is a wrapper for generic SQL calls. However, depending on the class who is calling the static class I would like to set the connectionString accordingly (its a public static string inside the wrapper class). If at all possible, I would like it to infer what connection string to use based on the context its being used and not have to pass it.

Is there a way to do what I am asking?

Is it bad practice to use a static class in this way?

I don't much care for having a non-static class who is just wrapping sql calls, having to maintain that object seems like extra work.

The wrapper:

```
public static class SqlServer
{
    private static readonly string SqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["foo"].ConnectionString;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Single point of entry for SQL queries that need to return a LIST of well-defined objects
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(SqlConnection sqlConnection, string sql, object param, int? timeout = null)
    {
        if (sqlConnection != null)
        {
            return sqlConnection.Query<T>(sql, param, commandTimeout: timeout).ToList();
        }

        using (var tempSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
        {
            tempSqlConnection.Open();
            return tempSqlConnection.Query<T>(sql, param, commandTimeout: timeout).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Should use "bar" connectionstring:

```
public class BarController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public int getUserId(string username)
    {
        var args = new
        {
            USERNAME = username
        };

        const string sql = @"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = @USERNAME";

        return  SqlServer.ExecuteQuery<int>(null, sql, args).Single();
    }
}
```

Should use "foo" connectionstring:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public int getUserId(string username)
    {
        var args = new
        {
            USERNAME = username
        };

        const string sql = @"SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = @USERNAME";

        return  SqlServer.ExecuteQuery<int>(null, sql, args).Single();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show you existing code.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are trying to do and show the specific parts of your code you are concerned about. Obviously, you can pass an argument if you want it to use a different connection string so what's the problem? And you could also use inheritance--I have no idea why your class needs to be static.

Comment: _"having to maintain that object seems like extra work"_ - if you need it in that many places, then _that_ is your problem.

Comment: Having a static class with a static connection string and changing this static connection string will cause concurrency issues and will end up executing the wrong query on the wrong database. I hope you are not meaning to change the static connection string in the let's say ExecuteReader method according to the caller

Comment: @LearningJrDev show what you have as well as an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added a small example

Comment: What you are probably looking for, is the [Repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your requirements, but I've seen solutions where a method will take a `SqlConnection` object as a parameter and then the method checks if that parameter is `null` and if so it'll reference a different connection string stored elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do what I am asking?
>   Is it bad practice to use a static class in this way?

There's always a way, but some things should not be done unless you understand the consequences. This is one of those things that should not be done. There's almost no good justification to force a static class to behave like a mutable object. So, yes, this is bad practice.

The SQL methods your static class wraps require a connection. The class can either provide the connection to those SQL methods using an argument passed in from callers, which is what you're doing now (an acceptable practice). Or the class can contain provide the connection itself, which means it will store it as a property, and use it while calling the SQL methods.

Using a static class implies that you want the connection string to be constant once initialized; it will not change for the lifetime of the process unless you expose a method (public property) to change it, which leaves you vulnerable to concurrency issues. By making it change depending on the caller, you are making it non-constant.

What you're trying to do is have the static class extract the value of the connection from the caller. This violates the encapsulation principle of OOP.

A better practice is to do the thing that you think "is extra work." Have each caller instantiate an object of this wrapper class, providing the connection string in the constructor arguments.

Comment: It wasnt as much work as I thought, I just ended up having the object be a static member of the apicontroller.

private static readonly SqlServer SqlServerObj = new SqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bar"].ConnectionString);

So that works. Thanks

Comment: Interesting. I avoid static members in general; they tend to lead to concurrency issues. In your case, it might work okay, but don't rely on this pattern too heavily or it will get you in trouble.

Answer (score -2):

You could pass the object into the static method you are calling and then switch on the type of this object to set the connection string.

e.g.

```
public static ConnectToDb(object _Object)
{
    switch(typeof(_Object))
    {
       //Set connection string...
    }
    // Do some stuff
}
```

Called via ConnectToDb(this)... or something

Comment: You cannot do this, since you are attempting to use a variable like a type. Also your method needs a return type.

Comment: @JamieR, and furthermore, you can't use `switch` on an instance of `Type`.

Comment: You're of course correct - I was trying to show sudo code and got the syntax slightly wrong, you could switch on something like _Object.GetType().ToString() though.  With the extra detail in the question I'm not sure whether this approach would actually be much help, but it is feasible...

Comment: If you're going to pass _anything_ at all into the static method, why pass the object? Why not just pass the connection string? But if you **really** want to do something like this, then instead of `object`, you should abstract it out: pass in an object that implements your custom interface, like `ISqlCaller`, which has a `SqlConnectionString` property or something. `public static ConnectToDb(ISqlCaller caller)...`

Comment: I do not recommend doing what I just said, btw. I stand behind my answer, not this comment.

Comment: @C.Knight If this was pseudo code then you should state that in your answer, some people automatically assume that you have posted functioning code.

Comment: question called for setting the connection string based on the context.  Passing 'this' as an object allows this, whilst passing a connection string would get rid of any way of implicitly using context.  Additionally the OP  stated that he was using a static class to avoid having to pass instances of the class around - the same concern would occur if using an interface - i.e. ISqlCaller